# why there is new line automatically after & before form tags in HTML?

Tags: html

When i make a form tag then its input and button come under the current line.And when i write sentence or make a button after form tag then it come under the form tag. i don't want to display input and button on new line. [Demo of my code is here.](http://digitalwander.blogspot.com/2013/11/photography-of-colombia.html)

```
  <form name="apple">
<input max="10000" maxlength="4" min="0" name="banana" size="4" type="number" />
   <input onclick="increase ();" type="button" value="View" /></form>
<button onclick="startDownload()">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `form` has a `display` of `block`. To have everything go on the same line use this:

```
<form name="apple" style = "display:inline">
<input max="10000" maxlength="4" min="0" name="banana" size="4" type="number" />
<input onclick="increase ();" type="button" value="View" /></form>
<button onclick="startDownload()">Download</button>
```

Comment: can you please ans my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591619/how-to-open-a-image-in-lightbox

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form name="apple">
<input max="10000" maxlength="4" min="0" name="banana" size="4" type="number" />
<input onclick="increase ();" type="button" value="View" />
<button onclick="startDownload()">Download</button>
</form>
```

You had the button outside your form.